# The convergence of a recurrcively defined sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations

Let $a_1=\sqrt{2}$ and $a_n=\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$ determine the convergence of the sequence and find its limit.

I know the sequence converges to $2$ and i can show this informally. But I don't know how to prove that formally.

Comment: Use induction. Show the sequence is bounded and monotone.

Comment: Use the fact that $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n$ and  $$|a_n-2|=\frac{|a_{n-1}-2|}{2+\sqrt{a_{n-1}+2}}\leq \frac{1}{2}|a_{n-1}-2|$$

Comment: @neuguy: At the first glance I thought Induction could work but terrified to show that. Now I've worked it out. (1) For monotonicity claim the sequence $a_n$ is increasing 'cause $a_2>a_1$ then assuming $a_n>a_{n-1}$ show that $a_{n+1}>a_n$ similarly (2) For Boundedness. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Show by induction that $a_n$ is increasing.

Then show by induction that $a_n$ is bounded above, e.g. try showing that $a_n \le 2$ for all $n$.

Then a theorem garantuees that $a_n$ has a (unique) limit $L$.

Then $L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{2 + a_n} = \sqrt{2+L}$, as the square root and addition are continuous.

Now solve $L = \sqrt{L+2}$. This will have 2 solutions of which one has to be eliminated.

Comment: It is easy to prove that $a_n$ is increasing, when we just know, that it is bounded. Can you elaborate the reverse order?

Comment: Increasingness is trivial, even without boundedness. I don't see how you use boundedness at all in a proof of being increasing.

Comment: $x^2-x-2<0$ for $x\in(-1,2)$ seems to be a natural way of proving the increasingness...

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I just note that $a_1 < a_2$ directly, and if $a_n < a_{n+1}$ then $a_{n+1} < a_{n+2}$ by applying the increasing function $f(x) = \sqrt{2+x}$ to both sides.

Comment: Oh, I see: your "then" from the second sentence is not a suggestion of an order of showing the properties. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Once proved the convergence by induction as suggested by Henno, you might be interested in seeing directly that the limit is $2$. So let's find $a_n$ (without the dependence from $a_{n-1}$) and then take the limit as $n\to \infty$. Here we have: $$ a_1=\sqrt{2}\\ a_2=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}+1)}=\sqrt[4]{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}\\ a_3=\sqrt{2+\sqrt[4]{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}}=\sqrt{2^{1/4}\left(2^{3/4}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}\right)}=2^{1/8}\sqrt{\left(2^{3/4}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}\right)} \\ a_4=\sqrt{2+2^{1/8}\sqrt{\left(2^{3/4}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}\right)}}=2^{1/16}\sqrt{2^{7/8}+\sqrt{\left(2^{3/4}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}\right)}} \\ a_5=\sqrt{2+2^{1/16}\sqrt{2^{7/8}+\sqrt{\left(2^{3/4}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}\right)}}}= \\2^{1/32}\sqrt{2^{15/16}+\sqrt{2^{7/8}+\sqrt{\left(2^{3/4}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}\right)}}} \\ \vdots \\ a_n=2^{1/2^n}\sqrt{2^{1-1/2^{n-1}}+\sqrt{2^{1-1/2^{n-2}}+...+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}}}.$$

The limit is $$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty}  2^{1/2^n} \times \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{2^{1-1/2^{n-1}}+\sqrt{2^{1-1/2^{n-2}}+...+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}}}= \\ \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}}=L \\ 2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}=2+L=L^2 \\ L^2-L-2=0.$$
Finally, using the quadratic formula we find $L=-1 \vee L=2$. Since $L>0$, it is $L=2$.